# How to POST data to URL (remote ASMX server) with PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, asmx

I have a http link that points to .asmx. I tried to call file_get_contents or fopen to POST data. But it returns that the http stream cannot be opened.

Is there any hint on open .asmx ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `allow_url_fopen` enabled in your PHP configuration?

Comment: Have a look at this article, it's on how to submit a POST request with PHP
[http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl](http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with being an asmx file. You need to send post data.

You can use the php curl function for it.

Example: [CURL](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/sending-post-form-data-with-php-curl.html)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now I try to access a page http://qchf-home.dyndns.org/test/. It returns Warning: fopen(http://qchf-home.dyndns.org/test/) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NestleCMS/TestPost.php on line 27

Warning: stream_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NestleCMS/TestPost.php on line 28

Comment: You cannot open a webpage like that. Fopen is used to open a file on the webserver it self. Perhaps it should be fopen '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NestleCMS/Test' ?

Answer (score 0):

as long as your request should be processed only on the server (and no JS or other client side processing should be performed) you can use  [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php):

```
<?php
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "your_link");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 ?>
```